# Ansible syntax issue running shell command and docker_container module

Tags: ansible

What I have is valid YAML but for some reason it's not valid for Ansible and the documentation on the Ansible site has some great examples of running the modules but there isn't any documentation on how the modules work together or if they can. I'm assuming I can run a shell module and a docker_container module in the same task but it appears to me as if Ansible is disagreeing with me. Here's what I have.

```
---
- name: Setup Rancher Container
   shell: sudo su_root
   docker_container:
     name: rancherserver
     image: rancher/server
     state: started
     restart_policy: always
     published_ports: 8080:8080

...

ERROR! conflicting action statements

The error appears to have been in '/opt/ansible_scripts/ansible/roles/dockermonitoring
/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact 
syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Setup Rancher Container
^ here
```

Because I'm runing this on RHEL 7 I need to be able to run the `sudo su_root` script to become root before ansible can communicate with the Docker API as docker runs as root.

So if I can't run this script and then run the docker_container I think that's a big problem with ansible.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming I can run a shell module and a docker_container module in the same task

Wrong. One task – one module.

There's `become` parameter to get privileged access, like:

```
- name: Setup Rancher Container
  become: yes
  docker_container:
    name: rancherserver
    ...
```

Comment: That's unfortunate because I do not have access to switch to the root account myself. Instead security constraints have me running a script to switch to root instead. I guess Ansible won't work for me then.

Comment: And what's inside `su_root` script?

Comment: not much but when I use the script it doesn't prompt me for a password and I'm not allowed the password.